# Google billing Consumable and Non-consumable

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I need to create a new In App Purchase in the Google console. The only 2 options I see are "MANAGED PRODUCTS" and "SUBSCRIPTIONS"

Inside "Managed products" I only get 1 options of "Create managed product".

However, in [Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_onetime) it refers to one-time products as 
"Consumable" and "Non-consumable"

Where is this set for an item?
What part of this am I missing?

We've created a few managed products, but it seems like we can only purchase them once - and we want to purchase them multiple times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, "Consumable" and "Non-consumable" is not a In-App billing term. They are just for explaining use cases.

From [Indicate a one-time product has been consumed](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_onetime) section,

> To indicate that a one-time product has been consumed, call the consumeAsync() method

If consumeAsync() is called, it becomes buyable again, means it becomes "Consumable".